# Как сделать перевод чисел в функции

Tags: c#

Как такой код записать в функцию, чтобы потом вызвать из метода обработки кнопки

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
string bin = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
label3.Text = bin;
```

Что я имел ввиду

```
public static string perevod(int val)
    {
        string res = Convert.ToString(val, 2);
        return res;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string res = perevod(val);
        label3.Text = perevod(val);
    }
```

Comment: что за "мэйн" тут имеется ввиду?

Comment: Да не мейн, событие кнопки. Исправлю

Comment: разобрался уже, так что спасибо за помощь

Comment: @SOFL, если какие-то из комментариев/ответов для вас были полезны - отметьте их.

Comment: как-то тут вообще фукнция не нужна. Нет смысла выносить одну строчку в функцию

Comment: учусь функциям...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите что бы элементы формы были доступны в main() что не тру.  то так

```
public static String Method(String fromTextBox)
 {

     int x = Convert.ToInt32(fromTextBox);
    string bin = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
    return bin;
  }
```

Далее присваиваете своему label.Если я вас правильно понял

Comment: А вообще, передача между формами производится с помощью паттерна MVP для WinForms.

Comment: Не совсем понял, почему аргумент fromTextBox не возвращает ретерн?

Comment: @SOFL, то как я это понял, исходя из вашего кода. Вызов в мейне я представляю так  label3.Text=Method(textBox1.Text); а элементы формы доступными в майн

Comment: Я примерно такой способ хотел

Comment: Добавлю в тему, посмотрите

Comment: А вы что имели ввиду? Там даже ключевое слово String(с большой буквы)), я такое и не не знаю

Comment: string это псевдоним на String. эти записи эквивалентны.

Comment: Я начинающий в c#, буду знать